# Exporting private key in Windows RT 8.1

Tags: winapi, windows-runtime, cryptography, certificate, windows-8.1

I am having troubles with exporting certificate's private key on WinRT 8.1 using new Cryptography API.

With help of [MS Cryptography and Certificate sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Cryptography-and-3305467b) I am able to list certificates from system certstore and get selected certificate's keypair using

```
CryptographicKey keyPair = await PersistedKeyProvider.OpenKeyPairFromCertificateAsync(cert, HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1, CryptographicPadding.RsaPkcs1V15);
```

But then, when I try to export the private key using

```
IBuffer pkey = keyPair.Export(CryptographicPrivateKeyBlobType.Pkcs8RawPrivateKeyInfo);
```

a *NotSupportedException* is thrown, no matter what blob type I use as the parameter.

The certificate I work with was imported from pfx by Windows Importer with Strong protection disabled and marked as Exportable, however it still seems that the Cryptography API has some problems accesing the private key (which I need for signing via SecureBlackBox library).

Does anyone know how to solve this issue and obtain the certificate's private key?

Comment: This is definitely related to the "strong key protection" mechanism, which prevents access to user private keys from all kinds of applications of unknown origin and intentions. There is a lot of information on the subject when searching for the exception message string.

Comment: You are correct, the MS sample was throwing an exception because of using synchronnous call to Sign function. Calling SignAsync resulted in displaying system confirmation dialog (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/12e4a640-3e43-40a8-baf0-55ee5b161689/a-bug-in-the-cryptographicengine?forum=w81prevwCsharp). I have removed the sample from the question as it is no longer relevant. 
However, the Export function does not have Async version...